# Get all the SQL Statement in an Informatica Workflow

Tags: sql, teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to get all the SQL Statements present in an Informatica workflow. (These can be from Post Sql, Pre Sql, Source  Qualifier etc). Could somebody guide me on how to about it.

Comment: If Informatica sets the QueryBand correctly you should be able to find those in `dbc.QryLogV` applying `GetQueryBandValue`.

Answer (score 0):

At the session level you can run the session once, copy the session log contents into a text editor (I use notepad++) and find all instances of SELECT, DELETE and UPDATE.

If you know all your connection names you can search for that too as the query statement is usually preceded by mention of the connection name